# Naturally floating unevenly-tall divs in rows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ltsjaaa2/4/)**

This question relates more to css than bootstrap I think.

Naturally floating divs in a two-column layout.

Case B: When right side is longer than left side, acceptable.

Case C: When left side is longer, next row's first div (#3) dives to under this row's shorter right side (#2), which is still acceptable, but #4 goes diagonally opposite to #3, which is too bad.

Case D: Possible to wrap every two divs with a row, but this is an ugly solution.

**Question:** Is it possible to naturally output all four elements under one parent, each may have different classes, to archive the look like D?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 my-class-p">
    <div class="col-xs-2 my-class-q">
    <div class="col-xs-2 my-class-r">
    <div class="col-xs-2 my-class-s">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `nth-child(odd)` to force every second element to the left side:

```css
.ribbon2 {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  background-color: black;
}

.cell {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  font-size: 24px;
  background-color: white;
}

.cell:nth-child(odd) {
  clear:left;
}
```

```
<div class="ribbon2">
  <div class="cell col-xs-6" style="height:6em;">1</div>
  <div class="cell col-xs-6" style="height:4em;">2</div>
  <div class="cell col-xs-6" style="height:4em;">3</div>
  <div class="cell col-xs-6" style="height:5em;">4</div>
  <div class="cell col-xs-6" style="height:4em;">5</div>
  <div class="cell col-xs-6" style="height:4em;">6</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ltsjaaa2/6/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this look using CSS columns

http://jsfiddle.net/ericjbasti/Ltsjaaa2/5/

The biggest change I made was adding this css

```
.columns{
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1px;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 1px;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 1px;
}
```

and modifying the html to look like this

```
<div class="row columns"> 

    <div class="cell cell-vert-pad col-xs-12">
        1<br/>C<br/><br/><br/>
    </div>

    <div class="cell2 cell cell-vert-pad col-xs-12">
        2<br/><br/><br/>
    </div>

    <div class="cell cell-vert-pad col-xs-12">
        3<br/><br/><br/>
    </div>

    <div class="cell cell-vert-pad col-xs-12">
        4<br/><br/><br/>
    </div>

</div><!-- .row -->
```

Basicly adding the class of .columns and change the widths of the columns to xs-12

IE didn't support this until v10.

Comment: Good! I knew the column-count style but did not think that it can be used in this issue.  Waiting for other people to give a solution which preserves the Z-order (instead of this solution's И-order).

Comment: Yeah you're not going to get any pure (left to right) CSS versions. Thats going to rely on something like http://masonry.desandro.com/